# Common Lisp -----should be a lambda

Tags: syntax-error, lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun foo(x y)(format t "X: ~a~%" x))
```

the function above works fine, 
but

```
(defun foo(x y) ((format t "X: ~a~%" x) (format t "Y: ~a~%" y)))
```

it prompts

```
"*** - SYSTEM::%EXPAND-FORM: (FORMAT T "X: ~a~%" X) should be a lambda"
```

How can I do to fix the compile error if I want to print parameters x, y separately ?

Comment: Searching for that exact error message turns up the exact problem;  you have too many parentheses.  It should be `(defun name (args...) (format ...) (format ...))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had too many parentheses. It should be:

```
(defun foo (x y)
  (format t "X: ~a~%" x)
  (format t "Y: ~a~%" y))
```

In all Lisp dialects, parentheses are syntactically significant. You cannot add or subtract them willy-nilly.

Comment: wow, thanks for your prompt response!!

Answer (score 6):

The error message of this particular implementation is not that helpful.

Simple sequencing of forms is allowed in the body of functions and many other places:

```
(defun foo ()
  (form-a)
  (form-b))
```

Where it is not allowed, one can use for example the `progn` operator, which returns the values of the last form:

```
(if (> a b)
  a
  (progn
    (print "smaller")
    b))
```

The error message comes because of the constraints of Lisp syntax:

```
((print "a")
 (print "b"))
```

Above is not valid, since the first element in a Common Lisp expression needs to be either:

- a special operator symbol
- a macro symbol
- a function symbol
- or a lambda expression `(lambda (a b c) ...)`

and `(print "a")` is neither of those four.
Since you had a list as the first form, the Lisp system told you that this list did not look like a proper lambda expression.

An example for such a valid form using a lambda expression as the first element is:

```
((lambda (a b) (+ a b 22))
 (+ 3 4)
 (+ 6 7))
```

Comment: thanks for your specific explaination, I understand that better